# Referring to a variable using Field Calculator in QGIS Modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I need to use a variable inside Field Calculator in QGIS Modeler and don't know how.

`@variable` and `variable` don't work.

Comment: Welcome to GIS Se. As a new user, please take the Tour. Most good questions take a paragraph or three to explain. Please Edit this question to describe your issue more completely. For example, what variable are you refering too ? Why did you tag arcpy and qgis ? It's 2 different context

Answer (score 5):

Define a variable under project properties.
[image]

Once the variable is created, use it in the field calculator with this syntax, but using the name of your variable.

> @variable

[image]